# Script error: value too great for base (error token is "09")

Tags: bash, decimal, octal

I am having script to determine day/night for rrdtool graphs:

```
# Calculating Civil Twilight based on location from LAT LON
DUSKHR=`/usr/bin/sunwait sun up $LAT $LON -p | sed -n '/Sun rises/{:a;n;/Nautical twilight/b;p;ba}' | cut -c 45-46`
DUSKMIN=`/usr/bin/sunwait sun up $LAT $LON -p | sed -n '/Sun rises/{:a;n;/Nautical twilight/b;p;ba}' | cut -c 47-48`
DAWNHR=`/usr/bin/sunwait sun up $LAT $LON -p | sed -n '/Sun rises/{:a;n;/Nautical twilight/b;p;ba}' | cut -c 30-31`
DAWNMIN=`/usr/bin/sunwait sun up $LAT $LON -p | sed -n '/Sun rises/{:a;n;/Nautical twilight/b;p;ba}' | cut -c 32-33`

# Calculating sunset/sunrise based on location from LAT LON
SUNRISEHR=`/usr/bin/sunwait sun up $LAT $LON -p | sed -n '/Sun transits/{:a;n;/Civil twilight/b;p;ba}' | cut -c 30-31`
SUNRISEMIN=`/usr/bin/sunwait sun up $LAT $LON -p | sed -n '/Sun transits/{:a;n;/Civil twilight/b;p;ba}' | cut -c 32-33`
SUNSETHR=`/usr/bin/sunwait sun up $LAT $LON -p | sed -n '/Sun transits/{:a;n;/Civil twilight/b;p;ba}' | cut -c 45-46`
SUNSETMIN=`/usr/bin/sunwait sun up $LAT $LON -p | sed -n '/Sun transits/{:a;n;/Civil twilight/b;p;ba}' | cut -c 47-48`

# Converting to seconds
SUNR=$(($SUNRISEHR * 3600 + $SUNRISEMIN * 60))
SUNS=$(($SUNSETHR * 3600 + $SUNSETMIN * 60))
DUSK=$(($DUSKHR * 3600 + $DUSKMIN * 60))
DAWN=$(($DAWNHR * 3600 + $DAWNMIN * 60))
```

which is used in rrdtool graphs as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
. inc/colors.sh
. inc/sunlight.sh

# Inside last 24 hours (mobile)
rrdtool graph /ram/temperature/graphs/sensors-24h-inside-mobile.png \
--alt-autoscale \
--slope-mode \
--width 638 --height 337 \
--border 0 \
--font AXIS:13:0 \
--color BACK#363636 --color CANVAS#363636 --color GRID#999999 --color MGRID#B5B5B5 --color FONT#CCCCCC \
--x-grid MINUTE:60:HOUR:1:MINUTE:360:0:%R \
--y-grid 1:1 \
DEF:Obyvacka=ds_temperature.rrd:O:AVERAGE \
CDEF:nightplus=LTIME,86400,%,$SUNR,LT,INF,LTIME,86400,%,$SUNS,GT,INF,UNKN,Obyvacka,*,IF,IF \
CDEF:nightminus=LTIME,86400,%,$SUNR,LT,NEGINF,LTIME,86400,%,$SUNS,GT,NEGINF,UNKN,Obyvacka,*,IF,IF \
AREA:nightplus#303030 AREA:nightminus#303030 \
CDEF:dusktilldawn=LTIME,86400,%,$DAWN,LT,INF,LTIME,86400,%,$DUSK,GT,INF,UNKN,Obyvacka,*,IF,IF \
CDEF:dawntilldusk=LTIME,86400,%,$DAWN,LT,NEGINF,LTIME,86400,%,$DUSK,GT,NEGINF,UNKN,Obyvacka,*,IF,IF \
AREA:dusktilldawn#222222 AREA:dawntilldusk#222222 \
LINE2:Obyvacka$GREEN:
```

and sometimes (I have not determined a pattern yet) I will get following error:

```
inc/sunlight.sh: line 15: 18 * 3600 + 09: value too great for base (error token is "09")
ERROR: invalid rpn expression in: LTIME,86400,%,19920,LT,INF,LTIME,86400,%,,GT,INF,UNKN,Obyvacka,*,IF,IF
```

But it looks, that it only happens around 23 hours mark.

I have found many solutions, but I can't apply single one to my script.

Answer (score 2):

Numbers in bash with a leading zero are, like in many other programming languages, interpreted as octal. Hence the `value too great for base`, as octal digits only go from 0 to 7.

The solution is to tell your script that the variables `SUNRISEHR`, `SUNRISEMIN` etc are decimal and not octal. This can be done by prefixing the variable name with `10#`, as follows:

```
SUNR=$((10#$SUNRISEHR * 3600 + 10#$SUNRISEMIN * 60))
SUNS=$((10#$SUNSETHR * 3600 + 10#$SUNSETMIN * 60))
DUSK=$((10#$DUSKHR * 3600 + 10#$DUSKMIN * 60))
DAWN=$((10#$DAWNHR * 3600 + 10#$DAWNMIN * 60))
```

Minimal example:

```
$ export A=09; echo $(($A+1))
bash: 09: value too great for base (error token is "09")

$ export A=09; echo $((10#$A+1))
10
```

Comment: Solution so simple, if you know what you are doing. It is working as a charm now. And I do understand it because of your minimal example. Thank you very much.

Comment: Ou, it was working as a charm for some hours, but getting now **inc/sunlight.sh: line 15: 10# 1 * 3600 + 10#91 * 60: syntax error in expression (error token is "1 * 3600 + 10#91 * 60")
inc/sunlight.sh: line 16: 10# 1 * 3600 + 10#94 * 60: syntax error in expression (error token is "1 * 3600 + 10#94 * 60")** errors.

Comment: Looks like there's a space in front of the `1` in one of your variables. To remove alle spaces from a variable in bash you can do the following: `export A=" 1"; echo "${A// }"`

Comment: I could not agree more @jbr. Your minimal example is working as a charm, but I can't seem to implement it into my script. I've tried - no luck. _Bash is stronger than my ability to learn :(_

Comment: Like this? e.g.
`SUNS=$((10#${SUNSETHR// } * 3600 + 10#${SUNSETMIN// } * 60))`

Comment: That looks about right, `export a=" 09"; echo $((10#${a// }+1))` works for me